# I need a source of information about DirectX's assembler

Tags: windows, assembly, shader, directx

In general, I am learning **DirectX assembler's language** (so far, specifically for DirectX 9). So far, I am studying by the book *"Learn Vertex and Pixel Shader Programming with DirectX 9"* by James C. Leiterman.

The fact is that, having studied (more or less) how **DirectX's assembler works**, I came across the fact that I not know how to **assemble** this code. In the above-mentioned book, only the "list of tool-applications for working with shaders" is written, but the book does not say whether they **assemble** code or just compile high-level code. And if they assemble, then there is not yet said how to use them.

Here is a list of applications-tools given in that book; I quote:

> When assembling or compiling your shader code, you will most likely be using one of the following tools:
>
> - nvasm.exe: nVidia –V&P Macro Assembler.
> - psa.exe: Direct3D 8 Pixel Shader Assembler.
> - vsa.exe: Direct3D 8 Vertex Shader Assembler.
> - xsasm.exe: Xbox Shader Assembler
> - cg.exe: Cg (C for graphics) compiler is limited in scope to the hardware platform.
> - fxc.exe: HLSL compiler provided with DX9 SDK, which optimizes code for all hardware platforms.
> - RenderMonkey.exe: RenderMonkey.
>
> One noteworthy item is that development of nvasm has stalled, so it only supports ps.1.3 and thus has limited use.

(Programs *psa.exe* and *vsa.exe* are not found in folder *Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)*. There I found only *fxc.exe* and I searched the Internet for information on how to use this *fxc.exe*, but it says that this program is for compiling shaders written in [HLSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Shader_Language), and I do not need that.

I did not look for the remaining unofficial, because these are not official programs from Microsoft, and therefore they can stop supporting, and, in short, why I need "strange" applications if they are from Microsoft. Moreover, since I am doing programming under Windows, then Microsoft programs will be more reliable. Although, if I will not find official ones at all, then I probably will have to use unofficial ones at least to somehow use the video-accelerator's/video-card's full power).

So, I looked at a lot of things on the Internet for finding a way to assemble code written in **DirectX assembler's language**, but it was not found.

What are the sources of information (most understandable, of course) about assembling of shaders in **DirectX assembler's language** (preferably by some tools from Microsoft)?

Anyone knows something about how to assemble shaders which written in **DirectX's assembler's language** (preferably by tools from `Microsoft`)? But exactly about **DirectX assembler's language**, and not something high-level like [`HLSL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Shader_Language). Since it's no use for me to study DirectX's assembler if i will can't assemble it into program.

Comment: Hey! Unfortuntelly StackOverflow is not intended for recommending something, please, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic 
However, technologies and apps in your post above are dead for many years. SPIR-V and DXIL (if you're keen on DirectX) are the languages closest to the assembler you mentioned.

Comment: Afaik assembly is not a supported __authoring__ format in modern DirectX anymore

Comment: [Please don't post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1474685/485119).

Comment: Related: *[Is it allowed to ask identical questions in different languages (not programming languages)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335297/)*, *[Cross-posting between localized Stack Overflow versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270047/)*, and *[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)*.

Comment: What is "DirectX assembler"? Isn't DirectX just a [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) interface (DirectX being a rebranding of COM)? Why is it related to assembly language?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, "DirectX's assembler's language", which called like that in book which i noted is exists. But it's not this "assembler" as you used to see usually. "DirectX's assembler's language" is just language, which will be translated to byte-code, which in turn will be translated by video-accelerator's driver in code which more understandable for video-accelerator and then will be executed. And it calls "DirectX's assembler's language" because it is most low-level and detailed for coding in `DirectX`. High-level coding in `DirectX` does by `HLSL` language.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Khmph.. Cross-posting with translated version of question is more effective than just leaving yourself (and others) without answer. It's too long to write explaining for me there, so i just will send to you this link of this guy, he (and others in same questions about cross-posting-with-translation) explained almost as i would explain that: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341304/19576766

Answer (score 4):

Support for *compiling* "DirectX Byte Code (DXBC)" assembly was dropped in the Direct3D 9 era.

Only 'reading' the assembly output from the `FXC.EXE` HLSL compiler was supported. Tools like `VSA.EXE` and `PSA.EXE` only supported Shader Model 1.1 - 3.0 and were last shipped in the legacy DirectX SDK (November 2008). The Pixel Shader Model 1.x models were very constrained (usually only a few instructions slots) so hand-written shader assembly was very common in those days, but it was all HLSL only after that.

There's no Shader Model 4.0 or 5.0 assembler for DXBC. The FXC.EXE HLSL compiler signed the resulting binary blob and the Direct3D 10 - Direct3D 12 APIs would only accept signed blobs. This was intended to simplify the driver authoring so they could count on specific coding patterns would be seen when doing the DXBC to vendor microcode translations. The assembly language itself is documented on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx9-graphics-reference-asm) with Shader Model 4 and 5 content.

> Note that as part of some recent open sourcing efforts, there *is now* a supported NuGet package for doing the DXBC signing if so desired. See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/open-sourcing-direct3d-9-on-12-and-the-release-of-the-dxbc-signer-nuget-package/). This could be an option for someone who wants to write their own DXBC assembler tool, but mostly exists for transcoding of DXBC to DXIL.

Shader Model 6 uses "DirectX Intermediate Language (DXIL)" and is fully open-source on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler/blob/main/docs/DXIL.rst).

Comment: @Chuck_Walbourn, Thanks for this information, but it’s not problem for me to use DirectX 9 and shader model 3.0. That’s my goal, because i want to support very old computers. So, could you say how (and which) to use programs for assembling DirectX code?

Comment: You'd have to dig up a legacy DirectX SDK of November 2008 or earlier to find the VSA and PSA tools.